# Angular 4.1.0 in Plunker: adding component returns 404 XHR Error

Tags: javascript, angular, components, plunker

I'm trying to use Angular 4 with Plunker and I can't manage to add a new component. The URL is:
https://plnkr.co/edit/1umcXTeug2o6eiZ89rLl?p=preview

I've just created a new component - `mycomponent.ts` - with the minimum of declarations.
Then, in `app.ts`, I'm adding the importing declaration:

```
import {MyComponent} from "./mycomponent";
```

and add the component in the declarations array within the @NgModule decorator:

```
 declarations: [ App, MyComponent ],
```

This last bit breaks it and returns a 404 XHR error. So far I just played with changing the import declaration ("./" or not), inline/URL template for the component template, chrome/firefox browsers but nothing works so far. I'm inclined to think it's Plunker's fault :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of `mycomponent.ts` to `src/mycomponent.ts` and it will work.

The error is because it can't include the component (bad pathing).

Don't forget to add `<combo-compo></combo-compo>` to your `app.ts` template.

Check it out:

[image]

Comment: excellent stuff but how did you know that??! later: oooh because the other app related files are in src/.....pffffsst

Comment: Because the error means that angular could not include `MyComponent`. So I started looking at pathing, saw that `main.ts` and `app.ts` had `src` as a parent folder. So I remembered that the code, in angular is in `src` while the libraries and angular stuff are in `node_modules`.