# Plunkr with Angular: Error loading https://run.plnkr.co/.../src/mycomponent.ts as "./mycomponent" from https://run.plnkr.co/.../src/app.ts

Tags: angular, plunker

I cannot get Plunkr to load my simple Angular 2 application

The project can be found here: [https://plnkr.co/edit/SDtOiIBkNsb36XM1zX79](https://plnkr.co/edit/SDtOiIBkNsb36XM1zX79?p=info)

When I run it, the browser window gets stuck on `Loading...` and in the console, I get this error:

```
Error: (SystemJS) SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.18/dist/zone.js:392:26)
        at Zone.run (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.18/dist/zone.js:142:43)
    Evaluating https://run.plnkr.co/fjg2NzuQ2f38zFXu/src/mycomponent.ts
    Error loading https://run.plnkr.co/fjg2NzuQ2f38zFXu/src/mycomponent.ts as "./mycomponent" from https://run.plnkr.co/fjg2NzuQ2f38zFXu/src/app.ts
```

There was a [similar question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678614/angular-4-1-0-in-plunker-adding-component-returns-404-xhr-error), but the issue there was not putting `src/` before the file name. I've ensured my paths are all correct and I still get the error.

Comment: this is an alternative and i am not promoting anything but you can try stackblitz and it is much easier and fun to use like you are using your own machine

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/nhSZSqFAhqZAOQp0LYSo?p=preview

Comment: I'm curious how are you going to use router without `router-outlet`

Comment: @yurzui how did you fix it? what did you change?
Thanks for pointing that out - I forgot about `router-outlet` ?

Comment: See the answer below. I also added `./src` to `templateUrl`

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the `'` after the selector name.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component', // missing ' after selector here
  templateUrl: './mycomponent.html'
})
```

Fixed plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/11WmtxKehLksFntitYGr?p=info

Answer (score 0):

### Possible Solution

Error states :-/src/mycomponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  // templateUrl: './src/mycomponent.html'
  template: '<h3>The current user is {{currentUser}}</h3>'
})
```

### And the routing error is resolved in plunker

The Plunker link:-

https://plnkr.co/edit/WhIvfdXeI0isq8NdFGIz?p=preview